# UICollectionView didSelectItem returning wrong indexpath

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm using a `UICollectionView` in my app to let the user choose between a couple of cities and restaurants in these cities.

First, I'll load the cities with the restaurants in them.

```
cities = RestaurantsLoader.cities()
```

I'll then fill up the `UICollectionView` with them.

```
extension RestaurantPickerViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1
    }
}
```

And then display them (with a `UILabel` because I haven't gotten to creating a custom cell yet)

```
extension RestaurantPickerViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cities[section].restaurants.count
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return cities.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "normalCell", for: indexPath)  
        cell.viewWithTag(123)?.removeFromSuperview()

        let label = UILabel(frame: cell.bounds)
        label.text = cities[indexPath.section].restaurants[indexPath.item].name
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.tag = 123
        cell.addSubview(label)

        return cell
    }
}
```

Now, I implemented the `didSelectItem` function of the `UICollectionView`.

```
extension RestaurantPickerViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath)
    }
}
```

However, this indexPath is almost always off. When I press a cell located at section: 1, item: 25, it'll print section: 2, item: 0 for example. I find this really odd and haven't really come across something like this before. What am I doing wrong? Or how can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you did implement `didSelectItemAt:` and not `didDeselectItemAt:`?

Comment: Yes, 100% I'm afraid.

Comment: Are you sure you're counting right? `indexPath.section` and `indexPath.item` are both "zero-based". What do you get if you tap on the very first item? Do you get `section: 0 item: 0`?

Comment: Are you able to find some sort of vague pattern based on items' visibility? If so, the problem might be with relationship of the flow delegate and reusable cell.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use   "indexPath.item"